# How can I find which package has a source that no longer exists?

Tags: debian, apt

Every time I run `sudo apt-get update` on my Debian Bullseye install, it fails with:

```
Ign:3 http://ftp.utexas.edu/dotdeb stable InRelease
Ign:3 http://ftp.utexas.edu/dotdeb stable InRelease
Err:3 http://ftp.utexas.edu/dotdeb stable InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ftp.utexas.edu'
Fetched 7,491 B in 8s (922 B/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.utexas.edu/dotdeb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ftp.utexas.edu'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I don't remember installing anything from `ftp.utexas.edu`, how can I find out which package I have installed that has this source?

Moreso, how can I fix this error?

More information: This is my current `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ bullseye-security main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian-based systems store their available repositories either in the main `/etc/apt/sources.list` file, or in individual files under the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory. So this command should show you what file(s) mention the repository you are looking for:

```
sudo grep -R ftp.utexas.edu /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

You can then edit the relevant file(s) and remove the line mentioning this repository or, if that is all that is present in that file, delete the file entirely. Then just run `sudo update` and you will have a clean set of repositories.

Comment: Thank you, it was `dotdeb.list` which now seems to be discontinued, I deleted it and apt-get update runs fine. Thanks!